# Object of type 'Object' cannot be converted to type 'Array'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, post

I have read about this error many articles, I have tried many solutions but nothing is working! I am stuck with this error since 3 days I hope someone can help me, thanks!
What I'm doing is calling my webservice from my mypage.aspx through two ways:

A-)

```
MyWebservice.MyWebMethod("test",LunchMyFunction);

function LunchMyFunction(response) {
   alert(response); // [object Object] 
   var gridView = $find('<%= MyGridView.ClientID %>');
   gridView.set_dataSource(response);
   gridView.dataBind();
}
```

Here the gridview is filled properly and everything is ok.

B-)

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'MyWebservice.asmx/MyWebMethod',
         data:{ testVal : "test" },
         success: function (response) {
            alert(response); // [object XMLDocument]
            var gridView = $find('<%= MyGridView.ClientID %>');
            try {
            gridView.set_dataSource(response);
            } catch (err) {
               alert(err);
            }
            gridView.dataBind();
         },
         error: function (err) { alert(err.statusText); }
});
```

Here my web method is completing it's work but when it comes to setdatasource : an error is thrown: 
**Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object of type 'Object' cannot be converted to type 'Array'. Parameter name: value**

I thought that this error is thrown because response type is different in both cases, so I have tried to set types as json to return [object Object]. After returning Object the method still throws the same error. I have tried ScriptMode="Release" in my ToolkitScriptManager which is in my Master page not in mypage.aspx, but nothing have changed.

```
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ScriptMode="Release" ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" AsyncPostBackTimeout="600" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference path="MyWebservice.asmx" />
    </Services>
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference path="~/JavaScript/WebKitFix.js" />
    </Scripts>
 </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

The assembly of cc1 is AjaxControlToolkit, and mypage.aspx is included in Master Page. Any idea about what could be the problem? How can I resolve it?

Comment: You are getting response as an object `{}` but datasource is expecting an array `[]`.  Hence error

Comment: @Rajesh Why calling the same function is returning response in two different ways? how can I fix it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after searching I discovered that in the second method response is:

```
{"d":[{"__type":"UploadedFile","Success":"Success","UploadedURL":"Uploaded URL"}]}
```

while what I need was  **response.d** to return this:

```
[{ "__type": "UploadedFile", "Success": "Success", "UploadedURL": "Uploaded URL"}]
```

That was my error, thank you